# build failed: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 10 declared in library

Tags: android, gradle

I get `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 10 declared in library` for a library in my project. but, in the library minsSdkVersion is already defined as 10 in grandle also androidmanifest file. Why Android Studio insists it is 9 and does not let the project compile

Comment: try to `Sync Gradle`

Comment: I did it already. but does not effect